# Passing inout port through hierarchy in Vivado

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, vivado

I am trying to build a driver module for the SMI interface on my ethernet PHY.  My top level module contains the following ports with eth_mdio marked as inout.

```
    module top
    (
        input        clk_100,
        input        cpu_rst_n,

        output       eth_mdc,
        inout        eth_mdio,
        output       eth_rstn,
        inout        eth_crsdv,
        inout        eth_rxerr,
        inout  [1:0] eth_rxd,
        output       eth_txen,
        output [1:0] eth_txd,
        output       eth_clkin,
        inout        eth_intn,
        input  [15:0] sw,
        output [15:0] led,
        input         btnc
    );

    ...

    smi smi_inst
    (
        .clk_50(clk_50),
        .rst_n(rst_n),

        .valid(read_reg),
        .write(0),
        .phyaddr(0),
        .register(sw[4:0]),
        .read_value(led),

        .eth_mdc(eth_mdc),
        .eth_mdio(eth_mdio)
    );

    endmodule
```

Inside the top module I create an instance of a submodule called smi which has the following ports.

```
module smi
(
    input         clk_50,
    input         rst_n,

    output        ready,
    input         valid,
    input         write,
    input  [4:0]  phyaddr,
    input  [4:0]  register,
    input  [15:0] write_value,
    output [15:0] read_value,

    output reg    eth_mdc,
    inout         eth_mdio
);
```

Inside of smi I assign eth_mdio as follows...

```
assign eth_mdio   = state == STATE_IDLE ? 1'b0 : (state == STATE_READ ? 1'bz : send_buffer[64]);
```

When I go to synthsize the design I get the following critical warning...

> [Synth 8-5744] Inout buffer is not created at top module top for the pin eth_mdio, other connections may not have buffer connection ["/home/chase/workspace/EthernetTest/src/top.v":3]

What is causing this and how can I fix it?  How can I pass an inout through the hierarchy?

Comment: Try putting parenthesis around `state == STATE_IDLE`, like so: `(state == STATE_IDLE)`

Comment: also, you've got a bunch of inout ports that should probably just be input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that I had used Bi-directional port inside a hierarchy but to be 100% sure I tried a simple example.

That example passed synthesis in Vivado without any problems. However it maybe that it passes ***because*** the code is so trivial. Who knows what idiosyncrasies the Vivado synthesis tool has. This was what worked for me:

```
module bidir_top  (
   input         clk,
   output         I,
   input          set_in,
   inout          pad 
);

bidir bidir_0 (
   .clk     (clk),
   .I       (I),     //<
   .set_in  (set_in),//<
   .pad     (pad)    //X
); // bidir

endmodule // bidir_top  

module bidir (
  input  clk,
  output I,
  input  set_in,
  inout  pad
  );
reg [1:0] cnt;
  always @(posedge clk)
     cnt <= cnt + 2'b01;  

  assign pad = set_in ? 1'bz : cnt[1];
  assign  I  = pad;

endmodule  // bidir
```

You can try to make the tri-state expression as basic as possible as shown above. Maybe that works.

Alternative is to make a tri-state or read/write signal and pass all three signals (In,Out,Tri) to the top and there you have to make your I/O pads.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Oldfart said,

> Alternative is to make a tri-state or read/write signal and pass all three signals (In,Out,Tri) to the top and there you have to make your I/O pads.

This is my recommendation.  Handle all tri-states at the top-level if possible (I always use IO rings).  You may not be able to do this though (easily, i.e. without editing) if re-using a component/module that has bidirects on the ports, and in that case, there used to be (probably still is) a setting in synthesis for "push all tristates" (Pushes them to the top-level).

So, If you can't code it such that the tristates are "at the top", you can at least, with that setting prevent any mapping/PAR issues... last I knew there were no internal tri-states in an FPGA, and likely why you got your error.